# Completely remove "error list" from visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to completely remove "error list" from visual studio 2008, not disable it i want it gone. It annoys me to no end popping up endlessly, i guess i must be "doing it wrong" but w/e i just want to use VS without being alerted every other keystroke about some warning.

I've tried editing many different fields in the options (tools -> options) it has only slightly decreased the frequency of the error list popping up. I have also deselected errors, warnings, and Messages. and it pops up with nothing to display. unpinning it doesn't help either.

also upgrading to VS 2010 is not an option at this point.

**Im looking for a solution something like the following: remove a dll or config file responsible for this**

Also I still want the inline validation (the little squiggly marks, etc), but
the error list window annoys me.

Comment: Please give a specific scenario

Comment: Specific scenario: i want to see all build output in the Output window below

Comment: I agree the Error list is totally pointless, and gets in the way. It doesn't update properly and pops up suddenly when you're trying to see the output in the output window.

Comment: More then 10 years have passed but the error list window is still absolutely useless and annoying but still exists and automatically pops up

Comment: 03/26/2024 and I still have the same problem in VisualStudio 2022 Community

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I think this is probably exactly what you're wanting:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/16/hide-or-show-error-list-when-the-build-finishes-with-errors-vstiptool0022.aspx

> You can change this behavior by going to Tools -> Options -> Projects
>   and Solutions -> General and deselecting the "Always show Error List
>   if build finishes with errors".

I'm guessing this will work with ASP.Net as well, since that's building on the fly.

Comment: I plus-oned you, but VS still likes to popup the errors window even if I don't have any errors.

Comment: Thank you! What a relief! Worked for VS2013. Upped one.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this is still helping out with VS2013!

Comment: This checkbox appears to have no effect in VS2017.

Comment: Can't aggree with CoryNelson, it works in VS2017 as well as VS2019.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2022, unchecked and Error List window still pops up.

Comment: @MaxPlay funny it does NOT work in VS2019? Maybe provide an exact version.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and I also have to cope with the completely useless, annoyingly-in-your-face, and impossible-to-disable "Error List" window.

So, here is what I did:

1. Undock the "Error List" window to make it free-floating.
2. Resize it to the smallest size possible.
3. Move it out to some remote area of the screen where it is not so annoying.

[image]

A couple of additional tweaks might be necessary in order to prevent the "Error List" window from continuing to be an annoying menace, by stealing focus at random moments, even from its remote exile:

1. Within the "Error List" window there is an (unlabeled, of course, because why not) drop-down list which might contain the phrase "Build + Intellisense" or "Intellisense only"; change that to "Build only".
2. Go to Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> General and uncheck "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors".

<sub>Do not get me wrong, I am not some script kiddie who thinks that if no errors are visible then no errors exist; I think that errors are very important to see. But so far, the Build Output window has been serving this purpose just fine. If, in the modern era, there is a new need to be able to see non-build errors (such as intellisense errors and what not) then the "Error List" window has been, in typical Microsoft fashion, the most crude, ineffective, pestering, and brutally insulting way of covering this need.</sub>

Comment: I did this and put it in the furthest corner of the furthest monitor, but it doesn't matter, because it steals keyboard focus. And now that you can't see it, you don't even know why you lost focus while typing.

Comment: @DaveCousineau that's strange, I never had this issue. Either I use the mouse without realizing it, or I am spared from this because I have disabled the option to "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" under "Settings > Projects and Solutions > General".  I mean, obviously, this option does not exactly work, because the damned window just won't buzz off, but perhaps it prevents it from stealing focus?

Comment: I think that setting has helped, yes. I didn't really mean my comment as a criticism of your answer, because that is what I also had done for a while. Just sharing my experiences with this issue. This _is_ a good option to avoid having the window block your view over and over if you can't get rid of it. But it does still steal input focus, even while typing code.

Answer (score 5):

My 'Error List' was constantly displaying also (VS2012). I also hate it.
I turned it off years ago, but today it just started appearing.

It was being caused a unreadable packages.config file. For some reason that reports it's fail state through the yukky 'Error List'.

Fixing the packages.config file stopped the 'Error List' from appearing.

Comment: Thanks - this helps for me in VS 2019

Answer (score 3):

for VS2017, select the "Build only" value from the drop down list in Error tab. Refer to the image below:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: @Marc.2377: If not for you, it may help someone else. It doesn't need a downvote ;-)

Comment: Well, I was too blunt in my first comment, sorry about that. But I downvoted because this question asks how to disable the error list window entirely, and your answer instructs how to select which types of errors are shown on that window - and not how to disable the window. So, I don't think it is really an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Perfect, upvoted, thanks for this. Now it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Selected answer is incorrect because unchecking "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" does nothing to stop the dreaded Error List window from popping up on other errors, even if you change it to show only Build errors.

11 years later in Visual Studio 2022 it is still impossible to disable Error List window.

The only correct answer to the question "Completely remove error list from visual studio" is to uninstall Visual Studio itself which, thankfully, also removes Error List window.

Either that, or we should all get used to it, because Developer Gods from Microsoft want everyone to work in absolutely the same way as they do. Every workflow that differs from their own is wrong, and every thought that doesn't align with their grand vision is blasphemy.

It is [One Microsoft Way](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Microsoft/@47.6422344,-122.1391219,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x54906d71b804151b:0x1a52969ee03899e!8m2!3d47.6422308!4d-122.1369332) or the highway.

Answer (score 1):

Its only a temp solution, and it not overly simple, but it does work (On a version of Visual Studio 2019 in 2023).

1. Install SnoopWPF
2. Dock the Error List window separately.
3. Use Snoop to inspect the floating window
4. Hit "Hide" in the methods:

[image]

And voila, the evil ErrorList window is banished from the good villagers, will only terrorize the innocents after inevitably the bloat-crap-ware that is VS crashes and you have to restart....

Maybe someone can write the dll injection code to do this automatically - its non trivial but at least this proves it possible.

Answer (score 0):

On Error tab, you have Errors / Warnings / Info buttons. Click on Errors button (de-press).

hope it helps.

Comment: yes i have done that: "I have also deselected errors, warnings, and Messages. and it pops up with nothing to display"

Comment: Its a shame this doesn't work, logically it should - its where I'd install a hook "if nothing to filter, don't show". Down-voted because it doesn't answer the problem or provide a solution. Maybe this is where someone could write a dll hook to "fix" MS's broken IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning off inline validation.

Yes, I know that you still want it. But, seriously, how important is it? It's trying to validate code that is half-written. How valuable can that be?

First of all, as-you're-typing code validation is distracting. It makes it harder to focus on the problem you are trying to solve. For example, writing a function with a non-void return will display the "not all code paths return a value" error continually until you get to the end of the function. In the meantime, the editor is telling you that there is a problem. I am sure that people learn to ignore these things over time (I have never kept the feature on for more than a few minutes after a new VS installation, so I don't know), but if you are actively ignoring something, then what good is it?

Second of all, any good that the validation would be capable of is unnecessary, because those errors will be brought to your attention at compile-time anyway. Having an uninitialized variable pointed out to you while you are thinking through the algorithm does not improve the quality of the code at all verses having it pointed out when you try to run the program. The variable is still going to be initialized either way. And there is an extremely high likelyhood that you are going to fix the problem before trying to run the code anyway.

So I just don't see the point of it. I suggest turning it off, and then your problem goes away.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @Charlie Kilian, there is a flaw in VS in which .aspx files are not validated at all, unless the "Show live semantic errors" option is enabled for C#, rather than validating those pages at compile-time as would be expected.

Therefore, editing aspx files will require turning this option back on for validation.

I guess I'll be going back-and-forth with it from now on. I hope they fix this in future versions of VS.

I still think that doing a semantic analysis and error-reporting on code that is actively being edited is a fool's errand. (Of course, I have also been known to write entire programs in notepad, just to see if I could get it to compile and run correctly the very first time without the crutch of Intellisense. It feels pretty awesome when it works.)

Comment: ok, can i get a quick link to something on how to do this, (im also googling myself too)

Comment: I think it's this: "Tools" menu / "Options" menu item / "Text Editor" tree-node / "C#" subnode / "Advanced" subnode / "Editor Help" control section / uncheck "Underline errrors in the editor" and "Show live semantic errors" checkboxes.

Comment: That works for C# code, but it doesn't do much good with .aspx files which don't get compiled, but are interpreted at runtime.

Comment: @Charlie Kilian - Haphazard aspx validation is a chronic problem for me. Sometimes some aspx files are validated, but usually they aren't. I have always wondered why it was like that. But I don't see why turning off the option for C# should even affect aspx validation, since it isn't C#!

Comment: @Charlie Kilian - (continued) I actually mentioned this problem at the end of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565024/compile-errors-on-deployed-web-application-but-not-in-the-ide . I never thought about the possiblity that aspx validation was being intertwined with C# editor validation. Interesting.

Comment: @Jeffrey I just meant that turning off validation in favor of seeing the errors at compile time isn't a very good answer when the code being validated doesn't get compiled. But you are probably right that you can turn them on and off independently.

Comment: And I see that you were not right. Crazy. I didn't know that actually. But I'm happy to accidentally help uncover a bug.

Comment: I feel I would like this feature a lot better if you could toggle it on or off with a shortcut key.  I would like to keep coding until I think I'm finished and then be able to toggle it back on for a last pass to solve any mistakes I have made.