# How to disable javascript extensions in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Screenshot:

[image]

I got 4 errors and 2 warnings. With the errors, I don't know where did the rule come from. Since I'd installed VS 2017, I'd installed only 1 extension `Web Essentials`.

When I click the third error, it refered to [Form elements must have labels](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/2.1/label?application=axeAPI).

I don't know, I don't know why must it be an error? For html, I want to design whatever I want, not following the rule

> Each form element must have a programmatically associated label element.

or blabla.... I don't want any label in there.

My html looks like:

```
<li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs searchform focus">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control animated fadeIn" placeholder="Search & Enter">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
</li>
```

With the first warning. It shouldn't be a warning. Because I would never create a file name `hubs` and put it in the location `signalr/hubs`. Of course, it's still working. When I clicked on the first warning code, it refered to

> http:/ /www .bing .com/search?q=TS6053+TypeScript+File+not+found.&form=VSHELP (You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links)

So, why do I want to search an error that you know what's the error and how to fix it? A link that how can I fix it rather than searching?

The second warning: I'm not the author for the script, but it looks good. I'm using `rangy-core.js` plugin.

```
    selProto.moveToBookmark = function(bookmark) {
        var selRanges = [];
        for (var i = 0, range, rangeBookmark = bookmark.rangeBookmarks[i++]; ;) {
            range = api.createRange(this.win);
            range.moveToBookmark(rangeBookmark);
            selRanges.push(range);
        }

        // error in from here, line 3719
        if (bookmark.backward) {
            this.setSingleRange(selRanges[0], "backward");
        } else {
            this.setRanges(selRanges);
        }
    };
```

The warning message:

> Unreachable code detected.

If I understand right, `Unreachable code detected` meant:

```
if (a < b) {
    return smaller;
} else {
    return larger;
}
// Unreachable code detected.
return average;
```

The code in `rangy-core.js` looks good, after making a loop, the function can continue checking something.

Totally, all errors and warning are bad for me (in this case). How to disable them?

Comment: Are you just wanting to hide them in the Error List?

Comment: @joshmcode Yes. But if you can tell me what is the extension which actives the rules, I want to uninstall it. If not, hide them is a good idea for me.

Comment: See my answer below, option 3. I'm not sure if that is the extension, but it might be.

Comment: TypeScript is causing the last 2 errors, but you don't want to disable that. It will disable all the JavaScript editing features.

If you just want to not see anything, follow Option 2 and just hide the warnings. They will do no harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top 4 errors are from an extension in WebEssentials (which is just a pack of extensions) called "Web Accessibility Checker". These errors indicate that the code in your project wouldn't pass online accessibility checks.

You can remove that plugin by going to tools > options > extensions and updates > scrolling down to Web Accessibility Checker > Disable/Uninstall

See image below:
[image: Screenshot of disabling web accessibility checker in VS]

I strongly recommend you just hide the bottom two, but they are likely bugs. The below code will never return `average`.

```
if (a < b) {
    return smaller;
} else {
    return larger;
}
// Unreachable code detected.
return average;
```

The other one (missing file) will likely be an error at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what exactly you are wanting to do, there are a couple of possible options:

**Option 1: Disable Error List**

You could disable the Error List on build by going to Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > and then unchecking `Always Show Error List if build finishes with errors`. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809245/completely-remove-error-list-from-visual-studio)

**Option 2: Just hide the errors/warnings**

In the error list, if you click the `Error` or `Warning` labels, you can toggle displaying them. [image] Just click the error box or the warning box and they will toggle off.

**Option 3 (bonus: might work, but haven't tested it)**

It's possible that if you disable the TypeScript extension by going to Tools > Extensions and Updates and then searching for TypeScript, you will remove those JavaScript specific warnings. But this might also disable your JS Intellisense.

Comment: 3 will definitely make your js IntelliSense worse